# Converting pandas series to string list leaves brackets in string

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a series generated from a dataframe groupby then getting the unique values

I want to end up with a list of just the string values

```
unit_group = df.groupby(['Unit'])
unit_list = unit_group['Unit'].unique()
```

unit_list is a series with with an index on Unit

```
Unit
UnitA   [UnitA] 
UnitB   [UnitB]
```

What i want to end up with is

```
unit_list ['UnitA', 'UnitB']
```

Using tolist in many forms gives me 
    unit_list =  [ '[\'UnitA\']', '[\'UnitB\']' ]

I could strip off the brackets and such but i'd like to know why i'm getting the wrong values in the first place

Comment: Can you add reproducible sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways, but you could use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)

Say you use what you've been using to create the series `uniques`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2], 'b': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]})

uniques = df.b.groupby(df.a).unique()
```

Then this will make it into a single flattened list:

```
import itertools

list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(uniques.values))
```